# How can I confirm ‘yes’ to a terminal prompt asking for my confirmation?

Tags: terminal

I’m trying to delete my ssh key in terminal, I was asked if I was sure I wanted to do this (y/n), terminal is not accepting my “y” for an answer or just y. When I write yes it prints y vertically non stop. Please help!

I tried “y”, (y), and yes, but when I write the whole word it keeps printing y vertically non stop